# How do I write a bash script that pushes files from a different folder?

Tags: git, bash

I am writing a cron job that pushes files in directory "~/foo" to a remote server every hour.

The script that this cron job runs is located at "~/bar/backupScript.sh". Hence, I cannot directly run such git commands as `git commit -m 'backup'` because "~/bar" is not a git repository.

How do I run git commands that are relevant to files in "~/foo" from "~/bar/backupScript.sh"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cd ~/foo` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: and `cd -` if necessary to get back to `bar`.

Comment: or pushd/popd if there is need for a "directory stack".

Comment: Or do the `cd` inside a subshell. Exiting the subshell will return you to the previous directory.

Comment: Wow, thank you! That was very comprehensive. Just curious, how do you make a subshell?